# How do i make a single update request on ES having both "script" and "doc"..?

Tags: elasticsearch

My 'doc' request:

```
POST test_v2/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
{
  "doc": {
    "CD": {
      "middle": "prakash",
      "first": "raj"
    }
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": "true"
}
```

My 'script' request:

```
POST test_v2/_update/Z_nM_2wBjkGOA-r6ArOb
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "if(!ctx._source.containsKey('nested_field')){ctx._source['nested_field']=[]}ctx._source.nested_field.add(params.object)",
    "params": {
      "object": {
        "model": "tata nano",
        "value": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to join both this 'script' and 'doc' and make a single request for them please help me achieve this. i am using ES v7.3. According to ES I cannot have both of them inside a single request.

Comment: you can send nested field in first query, not able to understand purpose of second query

Comment: if i send nested_field in the first query then i am not able to append a new object every-time in my array of object field that is the nested field. so that was the reason behind using scripts as they allow us to append a new object in the array of objects. Also i have updated my code for empty params check.

Comment: Add your partial document to script itself. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2967

Comment: could you please give me an example on how do i add it to the script, using above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

ctx._source['CD']=params.object1 ---> will update or add new field

```
POST test3/_update/30RaAG0BY3127H1HaOEv
{
  "scripted_upsert":true,
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source['CD']=params.object1; if(!ctx._source.containsKey('comments')){ctx._source['comments']=[]}ctx._source.comments.add(params.object)",
    "params": {
      "object": {
        "model": "tata nano",
        "value": "2"
      },
      "object1": {
      "middle": "prakash1",
      "first": "raj1"
    }
    }
  },
  "upsert" : {}
}
```

Comment: it is giving me document missing exception.

Comment: POST <test3>/_update/<30RaAG0BY3127H1HaOEv> --> update with your index and _doc id

Comment: It is a single request  . In script two field are getting updated. Field CD will be created/updated and comments will be appended. I think I am not getting your actual issue. Can you elaborate it more

Comment: sorry that "two request" thing is right i misunderstood something, but this update request is not running as it gives document missing exception. index and id are right but i know that doc with that id does not exist i want to create it with this update request.

Comment: want to do something like "upsert" if doc doesn't exist then create it with the following fields and if it exist then update the doc.

Comment: similar to what we do with "doc_as_upsert" : true, that is missing from here.

Comment: it's working but the object1 fields are getting replaced completely when i make a new update request here such as 1st request object1 = {"f1":"v1", "f2":"v2"} and then in second request object1= {"f1":"v1"} Now after it  "f2" key value is getting lost. it was not happening in "doc" type update.

Comment: This will require a complex script where we will need to loop through all keys in n objects and then replace the object

Comment: yes the "doc" type update was performing it for us automatically. Is it very complex to implement or will it affect the performance of the query as such?

Comment: are we missing an option to make "upsert" here true as well, that will eventually solve the issue.

Comment: I went through https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html , have a cross check. In script we assign value to an object ex field1={}. So we are basically overriding the field. To handle this in script we have to get all keys in object and then update only key which needs to be changed, it will not work with any other parameter

Comment: ok, then i guess that we have to make changes to our script to make this work.

Comment: I would request you to please look into it and if u build a working solution then please post here until then i am working on it as well.